# Conditions of parameters to have bounded solution of Dynkin's equation in exit problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, parabolic-pde

Consider the following Dynkin’s equation in exit problem defined on unit disk $D_1(0)$

\begin{align}
\left(\cos\psi \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{\gamma-1}{r} \sin\psi \frac{\partial}{\partial\psi} + \frac{\beta}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\psi^2} \right) T(r, \psi) = -1,
\end{align}

where $T(r, \psi): [0,1]\times[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^+$ are constant parameters. $r$ and $\psi$ are radial and polar angle coordinates.
The boundary conditions are $T(r, \psi)|_{r=1} = 0$ and $T(r, \psi+2\pi) = T(r, \psi)$.

I tried to numerically solve the above equation and found that there is a critical $\gamma_c$ such that
when $\gamma < \gamma_c$, $T(r,\psi)|_{r=0} < \infty$; when $\gamma\to\gamma_c$, $T(r,\psi)|_{r=0}\to \infty$.
The dependence of $\gamma_c$ on $\beta$ can be approximately fitted by $\gamma_c \approx 1.73\times 10^{-7} \beta^2 + 2$.

[image: Plot of <span class=]$\gamma_c(\beta)$" />

I am wondering if the dependence of $\gamma_c$ with respect to $\beta$, $\gamma_c(\beta)$ can be analytically obtained.

My research area is theoretical physics. If there is something mathematically ambiguous in the above question, please let me know.
Thank you.